# Linear systems of inequations

Tags: matlab, math, optimization

Ok so I have a systems with 6 inequations and 3 variables, and a point that may or may not solve this system. To check whether this point solves the inequations is straightforward, my problem is when it does not solve the inequations to find the closest point that does solve the problem.

I will present an example of such a system: Ax<=b

A=

```
[  C11,  C12,  C13]
[ -C21, -C22, -C23]
[  C31,  C32,  C33]
[ -C41, -C42, -C43]
[  C51,  C52,  C53]
[ -C61, -C62, -C63]
```

b=

```
[ Cb1]
[ Cb2]
[ Cb3]
[ Cb4]
[ Cb5]
[ Cb6]
```

Pxyz=

```
[  pX,  pY,  pZ]
```

Does Pxyz solve Ax<=B ?

```
if all(A*Pxyz<=b)
accept point
else
get the closest point to Pxyz (by Euclidean distance) that solves the system. How?
end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on the question? Closest to what? what is the measure?

Comment: You may want to ask this in http://math.stackexchange.com/ also

Comment: @Arpi Hi. Closest to the point given (Pxyz). The measure can be Eucledian distance.

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thanks I did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Try one of these (tested with a 2D problem):

**Approach 1:**

```
[Psol,fval,exitflag] = fmincon(@(Psol) norm(Pxyz-Psol), Pxyz, A, b)
```

---

**Approach 2:**

If I understand correctly, you have a constrained linear optimization problem, more specifically a constrained linear least-squares problem which can be solved using [lsqlin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html). It would be something like this:

```
if all(A*Pxyz <= b)
  % accept point
else
  % get the closest point to Pxyz (by Euclidean distance) that solves the system
  C = eye(length(b));
  [Psolu, resnorm, residual, exitflag] = lsqlin(C, Pxyz, A, b);
end
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: seems logical. I will give it a try.

Comment: is this correct "lsqlin(A, Pxyz, A, b)"? should you have "A, Pxyz" as the first 2 arguments? or should it be lsqlin(A, b, A, b,[],[],[],[],Pxyz)?

Comment: You are right, that is not correct, I edited the answer.

Comment: Both seem to work thanks. For this particular case I think that lsqlin is a better solution. My problem now resides in efficiency as I am calling these functions millions of times, but that is a different problem.